# Unexpected result of ng-bind in angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs

```
            $scope.clickedNum = function(passedNum){
                $scope.string1='';
                $scope.numToDisplay=passedNum;
                for (var i=1; i<=passedNum; i++) {
                    $scope.string1=$scope.string1+'<img src="img/'+$scope.selectedItem+'.png" title="'+$scope.selectedItem+'" />';
                }
            }







<div id="figuresToDisplay" ng-bind="string1"></div>
```

I want some images to be displayed in the div having id="figuresToDisplay" using script, but result is coming as plain text not as image. Please guide me.

Comment: Use `ng-bind-html` instead of `ng-bind`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion it was very helpful to me. when I am using "ng-bind-html" (instead of ng-bind) and "$sce.trustAsHtml" filter together than only I am getting the desired result. Thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use $sce.trustAsHtml for this, Better way to do so is like this

```
app.filter('safeHtml', function($sce) { return $sce.trustAsHtml; });
```

and use it in your template

```
<div id="figuresToDisplay" ng-bind-html="string1 | safeHtml"></div>
```

or you can use it without creating filter,but If you are using this in various places I suggest you to implement filter.Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion it was very helpful to me. when I am using "ng-bind-html" (instead of ng-bind) and "$sce.trustAsHtml" filter together than only I am getting the desired result. Thanks again